# How can I retroactively import files into my Itunes library?

Tags: itunes, mp3, import

How can I get Itunes to move everything to my library retroactively. When I add new songs, it copies them to my library but I have a lot of music that I added before I discovered I could enable the auto import to library function. How can I get itunes to go back and copy all of those to the  Itunes auto-organized library?
My files are spread out all over the place, it would be nice to have them in one place.

Answer (score 6):

If you go to File -> Library -> Organise Library you'll get a pop up asking if you'd like to Consolidate Library, that'll move all the files into the iTunes music folder.

[Apple Support Document on how to do it.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1364)